# UICollectionView iOS 9 Performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I've developed an app which uses a UICollectionView to display a feed of posts. The app supports iOS7+. I'm currently testing the app with an iPod Touch (2G) with iOS7 and an iPhone 6 with iOS9. I'm testing the app using the very same view scrolling a collection view on the iPhone 6 and the iPod. I've seen a huge drop of FPS with the iPhone 6 (iOS9). The iPod works perfect and the scroll is far smoother than the iPhone 6. The only thing that's different between them is the iOS version, and of course, the hardware.

What do you thing? Is there anything I have to do to have a greater performance with iOS 9?

Comment: Does the iPod 2G support background applications?

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer here and see if this helps you: [iOS 9 CollectionView slowing down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724887/ios-9-collectionview-slowing-down/32767824#32767824)

I believe auto layout constraints with >= or <= are to blame.

Comment: I've updated the app constrains and now the scroll is fluent. I don't understand why this kind of constrains have this bad performance on iOS 9 while work pretty well on iOS 7 and 8...  Thank you!!!

Comment: What do constraints have to do with scrolling speed? Please, post the constraints code as it was, and as it is now. I simply must see this.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely something you're doing, and I'll bet it's due to a failing in your understanding of design patterns. In order to work with any Apple framework, you have to be able to make educated guesses as to how it was designed based on how you integrate its functionality into your own app.

UIKit requires the developer to not only possess the ability to recognize a given design pattern in someone else's work, but the ability to extend or integrate their work in only the ways it makes sense. Developers of UIKit are forward thinkers; they not only employed the best methods for achieving their aims, but set things up for you to do the same.

There is no diminishing of the UIKit product from version to version. Any way you intend to build on it, you can, if not by bolstering your knowledge, then by simply reproducing the parts of UIKit you want to use or extend. It is a simple framework—so basic that I'm surprised it's not open-source, save for the fact that it uses proprietary "physics" calculations for UI animation.

Here is a video showing a collection view producing each frame in a video, one at a time, in not only a player window, but in a collection view, too, and that as fast as the user can scroll the view:

[Using a UICollectionView as a UIControl [Video Skimmer]](https://youtu.be/eeS8InSe_ag)

```html
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eeS8InSe_ag?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The sample code is freely available to you, and is simple to follow. It is provided to demonstrate to each of the UICollectionView-related questioners and their answerers, once and for all, that it's a matter of education—not quality control—with anything UIKit.

More specifically, it shows a collection view being used as a skimmer control. For this demonstration, a sample app was written that loads the most recent video on the user's iPhone, and then allows frame-by-frame skimming by simply sliding a collection view of frame thumbnails.

To ensure perfectly smooth scrolling with little or no impact to CPU and memory usage (as compared to plain-text collection view cells), both the video playing in the background and the frames in each cell are rendered on the GPU.